# Building Solr Custom Request Handler - applying group clauses to query

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm writing a custom handler, inside which I will run multiple queries and then merge the results. Currently I am running into an issue with creating a query inside the Handler where I need to apply "group by" clauses...

This is how I am creating the query:

```
String q = params.get(CommonParams.Q);
...... 
Query myQuery = new WildcardQuery(new Term( "name", q )); 
...... 
ScoreDoc[] hits = searcher.search(myQuery , 100).scoreDocs;
```

My question is: How do I take the "q" variable and apply "group by" clauses so that the results are grouped?

Example:

I indexed following:

```
<doc>
<filed name=id>001</field>
<filed name=name>foo</field>
<filed name=color>red</field>
</doc> 

<doc>
<filed name=id>001</field>
<filed name=name>foo</field>
<filed name=color>blue</field>
</doc>

<doc>
<filed name=id>002</field>
<filed name=name>bar</field>
<filed name=color>red</field>
</doc> 

<doc>
<filed name=id>002</field>
<filed name=name>bar</field>
<filed name=color>blue</field>
</doc>
```

Is it possible to apply grouping to the "query" object in inside my request handler to group by id.

```
Query query = new WildcardQuery(new Term( "name", q ));
```

so that only 2 document will be returned?

I have googled everywhere online, I have not found any examples related to my question.

Comment: whats the need for custom request handler ?

Answer (score 1):

The [Result Grouping / Field Collapsing](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) feature, as of Solr 3.3/4.0 seems to be what you are looking for.  This allows you to pass a `group.field` parameter with the query, such as:

```
&q=name:something&group=true&group.field=id
```